# When should a non-virtual method be redefined?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

`virtual` methods are part of the C++ implementation of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism). Other than avoiding the overhead associated with RTTI<sup>**</sup> and method lookups, is there a compelling reason to omit `virtual`?

Assuming that `virtual` could be added to the base class at any time, what purpose would redefining a non-`virtual` method serve?

*<sub>**Whether it's measurable on modern CPUs or not is irrelevant to this question.</sub>*

Comment: May I ask if this is a question from a particular textbook?  I'm just curious!

Comment: Have you heard of CRTP? If you're not familiar with it look it up :)

Comment: @Yakk - Nope, just something I thought of during development.

Comment: Ah: Then as a bit of side information, `virtual` function overhead is very easy to measure on modern CPUs.  Every `virtual` call requires a lookup in the `virtual` function table for the instance's class (which can cause a cache miss), followed by following a pointer stored there to another address.  "Random" memory access and instruction jumps are among the worst performance hits on a per-instruction basis. (this is a description of a reasonably efficient implementation of `virtual` function pointers). Now, most code runs in context where performance is not important, but it is a serious hit.

Comment: @Yakk - True. I just didn't want to have answers sidetracked by the pros and cons of RTTI, hence the footnote :)

Comment: Virtual functions do not use RTTI.

Comment: @PeteBecker - RTTI is only available for classes which have at least one `virtual` method. `typeid` will return info on the base pointer when called on a pointer of non-polymorphic classes. So while `virtual` itself does not require RTTI, having a `virtual` method will turn on RTTI for that class, assuming it is enabled in the compiler.

Comment: @Unsigned - the first sentence of your question asserts that virtual functions use RTTI. That is incorrect, and that is what I commented on.

Comment: @PeteBecker - Ah, bad wording, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is little reasons to redefining a function that is no virtual. In fact I would recommend against it as what looks like the same function call on the exact same object could behave differently based on the static type of the pointer/reference used.

*Overriding* a virtual member function allows you to specialize the behavior of the derived type. *Overloading* a non-virtual member function will instead provide an alternative behavior, in which it might not be obvious to a casual reader which of the functions/behaviors will be executed.

Comment: `void read(size_t n, void* bytes)` in base, `template<typename T> void read(size_t n, T* instances)` in child --  a bit questionable, but...?  Covariant return types? (parent returns `Base`, child knows that the parent will hold `Derived` and provides a cast).  CRTP where the Derived implementation is called from the CRTP instance for syntactic sugar reasons (so you don't have to qualify `self()->Foo()` every time you want to call `Foo()` in the CRTP class)?

Comment: @Yakk: You cannot have *covariance* without overriding. In the case of `read` or the CRTP, if you have the same function name in the base and the derived types you hit the issue I mentioned: depending on what the static type of the pointer/reference you get different functions potentially causing confusion. By choosing a better/different name you can make things clearer and simpler to the user.

Comment: `struct Base { X* foo(); }; struct Derived:Base { Y* foo() { return static_cast<Y*>( Base::foo(); }};` is basically static covariance.  And not confusing at all.  Similarly for CRTP in some cases -- if parent statically forwards all calls to `foo` to child, the same name is not a source of confusion.

Comment: @Yakk: If `Base::foo` returns a pointer to a `Y` object why is that not in its signature? If it doesn't, the `static_cast<>` is wrong. Now consider `X* f(Base& b) { return b.foo(); }` and the call `Derived d; f(d);` Is it so obvious the dynamic type of the object returned by `f`?  If you see that code in the first place and you see the definition of `Derived`, is it obvious that it is not that `Derived::foo` being called? The rules in the standard are clear and are not confusing, but consider whether others might potentially make a mistake there.

Comment: Because `Base`'s `Base::foo` returns a pointer to `Y` if it is actually a `Derived`, and not all `Base`'s are `Derived` (which isn't that hard to arrange -- say, a value that is only set at construction, and `Derived` constructs `Base` with a `Y` in every case).  If you call `Base::foo` because you only know the object is a `Base`, you only get an `X`.  If you know it is a `Derived`, it covariantly returns a `Y`.  This is the exact same use case as a covariant `virtual` function, except in the `static` dispatch case.  As to "is `Base::foo()` a call to `Derived::foo()`", comments are wonderful.

Comment: @Yakk: Same difference. I have never found a design that did not have a strong code smell and redefined the same function signature in the derived type. If you feel that it is a good use case, propose it. I know it would not go past a code review in my group :)\

Answer (score 2):

One possible use could be for implementing a CRTP framework where default versions of functions are defined:

```
#include <iostream>

//This could be any higher-order function.
template<typename T>
class CallFiveTimes {
    protected:
    void docalls() const {
        for(int i(0); i != 5; ++i) static_cast<T const*>(this)->callme();
    }
    //Default implementation. If a lot
    //of different functionality were required of `T`
    //then defaults could make `T` easier to write.
    void callme() const {
        std::cout << "Default implementation.\n";
    }
};

class Client : CallFiveTimes<Client> {
    public:
    void useFramework() {
        docalls();
    }
    private:
    friend struct CallFiveTimes<Client>;
    //This redefinition will be used.
    void callme() const {
       std::cout << "Client implementation.\n";
    }

};

class LazyClient : CallFiveTimes<LazyClient> {
    public:
    void useFramework() {
       docalls();
    }
    friend struct CallFiveTimes<LazyClient>;
};

int main() {
   Client c;
   c.useFramework(); //prints "Client Implementation" five times

   LazyClient lc;
   lc.useFramework(); //prints "Default Implementation" five times
}
```

I've never seen this done in practice, but it may be worth considering in some cases.